# Stackdriver Alerting Policy notification in Microsoft Teams

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Any update here Any way to receive Google Stackdriver Alerting Policy to Microsoft Teams?

I tried via the "Static Webhook" option in Stackdriver and using a webhook incoming connector in Teams but this is not working. Is this still not compatible? Or there are any other way to get this working in a Team channel. I know already that "the outgoing webhook of stackdriver and the incomming webhooks connector are not compatible, as they use different formats and in microsoft teams chats/channels do not have an email address (only users do). looks like making a mailing list in office 365 is the best option so far"

Comment: what had you tried when using static webhook ?

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround you can use another channel.

For example you can configure the alerting policy via email, and send the notification to the Email address of your Microsoft Teams Channel.

In order to forward / send an Email to an MS Teams Channel, you need to know what is the Email address of your Team Channel, and is pretty simple, just find the Channel that you’d like to Email, find the ellipsis and then select “Get Email address”,[check this image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FVpd.jpg)

Once you’ve clicked “Get Email address”, just make a copy of it and you are ready to sent your Stack Driver alerts directly to your MS Teams Chanel using Email alerting configuration.

You can read this ["How to send an email to a channel in Teams"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-an-email-to-a-channel-in-teams-d91db004-d9d7-4a47-82e6-fb1b16dfd51e) guide on Microsoft Support site.

Other Workaround are you can use a service in the middle that catch the Stackdriver message (JSON) and converts it to MS Teams format and then send it again to the desired destination, but it maybe involves some development work to your team.

Also i can see Google have an active Feature request about your question. 
You can track the evolution [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/129671778) and I would recommend you to ‘star it’ in order to receive updates on its progress.

I hope the information I have provided will be helpful to you. =)

Answer (score 1):

It may have been resolved now, but I solved it by creating a Cloud Function through the link below.
https://github.com/Courtsite/gcp-monitoring-to-teams

I have confirmed that the Test Connection is also normally coming in as shown below, and it seems that you can get an Alert from GCP Monitoring to Teams by referring to the Github link below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0SwC.png)

I hope the information I'm providing will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using a webhook to send alerts to Microsoft Teams is not possible because the format used by the outgoing [webhook of Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks) and the [incoming webhook in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card) are different and so incompatible.

You have different notification options, like [Email.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#email) and others more, you can see [this public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options).